# Why merged entities are updated on insert?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-2.1

When inserting an entity, let say `article`:

```
Article::id
Article::text
Article::author -> User
```

The article has an author (ManyToOne)

```
User::id
User::name
User::created
```

if I fetch the user in the database using the entity manager:

```
$user = $em->find(1);

$article = new Article();
$article->text = "balh blah";
$article->user = $user;

$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

I only have an insert into the database which is correct.

```
INSERT INTO Article ...
```

Now if I use a user that is stored in the session (or cache):

```
$user = $cache->find(1);
$user = $em->merge($user);

$article = new Article();
$article->text = "balh blah";
$article->user = $user;

$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

I can see 2 queries in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO Article ...
UPDATE user set created="..." WHERE id = 1
```

and if user as more OneToMany relationship, each one of them is updated too. Knowing that the user entity did not change I don't understand why `Doctrine` is performing those update.
In addition, there is only the created (datetime) object that is updated, none of the other fields are updated.

I have no cascade setup so it should not trigger anything on Article persist().

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

What is your annotation for created_at column? And is there @PreUpdate annotation somewhere in your User class or BaseUser if it is extending one?

Also; try the same thing but without $em->merge($user). I never used it and I don't even know what it is used for but that might be the problem.

Comment: There is no lifecycle or preUpdate method in User or Article. The annotation for the created field is basic `@ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=false)`. I have to use merge because the user entity is stored in cache and the entityManager needs to know about it before the association is done.